# How can I compile an iPhone App with Flash CS5 without a Developer License

Tags: iphone, flash, flash-cs5

I understand Flash CS5 isn't the best way to make an app, but I'd really like to test out the apps I've made with it on my iPhone. Has anyone come up with a way to modify Flash CS5 so it doesn't require a Developer Certificate or Provisioning Profile (like the way you would modify Xcode so you can compile apps without paying $99 for the developer program)?

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could provide some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do realize that apps created with Flash CS5 will not be accepted on the App Store, right?

Comment: Yes, I realize that, I develop apps for Jailbroken Devices and submit them to Cydia.

Comment: This is not a good idea, but it's certainly a programming question. Voted up.

Comment: True, but he is asking how to bypass several points in Apples Licence agreement that is under an NDA.

Comment: This is the best question I ever saw about iPhone development. I hate the way that Apple obligates us to pay that crazy value!

Comment: @nathan that **Crazy value** you are referring to is used to test the apps every iphone developer submit. They care about the iphone users alot coz in the end they will say `what a bad(s@#t) device iphone is`. So you know they are have to make sure it works on iphone and for that they have to test it and for that they take the amount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paying $99 for a dev certificate only to have anything you make (most likely) rejected because it was made with CS5... lame.

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Adobes-iPhone-Packager-without-an-Appl/

works like a charm :)

Comment: why am i getting negative marks? that answered the question perfectly, there is a zip file with a fake certificate, you simply select that and you can compile iphone apps with Flash CS5?? 

apple fanboys are ridiculous

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I can see that your first sentence is an snarky editorial comment. Maybe be nicer.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. After testing a simple app on my device, I realized how unpractical it is to use CS5 for iPhone Development, but it's still fun to be able to. :)